# Getting Error Code "NoSuchKey" when hashrouter is a bad url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, hash, react-router-dom

I am currently working on error handling bad URL paths on a React application that uses HashRouter from `react-router-dom` deployed with AWS.

Problem: If a user enters characters before the hash (#) in the address bar `https://www.mywebsite.com/blahblahblah#/login` on my deployed dev site, then the page routes to AWS's error page with code NoSuchError.

Error (image provided below):

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
  <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
  <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

On localhost, given the same bad URL, the page stays on the current page with the bad URL, which is my expected behavior (ideally I would like the page to refresh and the URL to correct itself or for the page to redirect to a PageNotFound component) example: `http://localhost:3000/blahblahblah#/login`
Note: when characters are entered **after** the hash, the site redirects to PageNotFound just fine on both localhost and dev.

**Why isn't the deployed site behaving the same way as localhost?**

[Error with bad URL on deployed site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSz22.png)

[localhost with bad URL (stays on the page with this URL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkSJ0.png)

Urls before errors look like:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/#/login`

`http://localhost:3000/#/login`

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <HashRouter baseName="/">
            <IntercomProvider appId={REACT_APP_INTERCOM_APP_ID}>
                <App />
            </IntercomProvider>
        </HashRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

**App.js**

```
<Switch>

 <Route path="/" exact={true}>
   <Redirect to="/track_shipments" />
 </Route>

// Okta provided code (for authentication)
 <Route path="/login/callback" 
  render={(props) => (
     <LoginCallback {...props} onAuthResume={onAuthResume} /> )} 
 />

 <Route
  exact
  strict
  path="/login"
  render={() => (
     <Login {...{ setCorsErrorModalOpen }} /> )}
 />

 <SecureRoute
  exact
  strict
  path="/add_shipment"
  component={() => (
     <AddShipment theme={theme} /> )}
 />
                                    
 <SecureRoute
  exact
  strict
  path="/track_shipments"
  component={() => (
     <TrackShipments theme={theme} /> )}
 />

 <Route
   path="*"
   component={() => (
       <PageNotFound theme={theme} /> )}
 />

</Switch>
```

Thank you so much for your time.